# Wordpress custom template for feed in specific categories

Tags: wordpress, rss, feed

I'm trying to use a custom template for a podcast feed.  My podcast is a standard post defined by its category.  I would like to access it via the standard url: `mysite.com/category/podcast1/feed`

I can get the new template to work, but the code below removes the standard category filtering so I get posts from all categories with the new template.  When I try to add a new query and limit the posts it overrides all queries.  When I try to limit the query with `$query->is_feed` then it doesn't work either. When I var_dump the $query, the pre_get_posts hook is running the query twice, the first with is_feed as true and the second with false.  The last query it runs is 'showposts'.  Here's my code:

```
function my_custom_rss($query) {
    if ( 'podcast1' === get_query_var( 'category_name' ) ) {
        get_template_part( 'feed', 'podcast' );
    } 
    else {
        get_template_part( 'feed', 'rss2' );
    }
}
remove_all_actions( 'do_feed_rss2' );
add_action( 'do_feed_rss2', 'my_custom_rss', 10, 1 );

function feed_category_query($query)
{
    if ($query->is_feed && $query->is_category() ) {
        $tax_query = array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => get_cat_ID('podcast1')
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => get_cat_ID('podcast2')
                ),
            );

            $query->set('post_type','post');
            $query->set('orderby','post_date');
            $query->set('order','DESC');
            $query->set('tax_query', $tax_query);
            return $query;
    } 
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','feed_category_query');
```

How can I limit the query to only the feed, or reinstate the the standard query that I suppose was removed with `remove_all_acions('do_feed_rss2')`?

I'd rather do all of this with a custom plugin, but right now, whatever works.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue in my new feed template.  At the top I had:

```
$posts = query_posts('showposts=' . $postCount);
```

this was creating the second query that was overriding my pre_get_posts query.